# selectToUISlider: right slider overlapping issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

If you go here : http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support//

Then click and drag the second slider over top of the first one, let go, and then try to slide the second handle back to the right, it won't let you. It will only go left. I know this is an issue with the jQuery ui slider library, but I wanted to know if anyone has found a good work around for this issue using the selectToUISlider.

I do NOT need the first handle to move at all, it is a fixed value (I just did a display:none on the first one).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a quick look at the source, you might be able to hack the jQuery UI slider code to your purposes. I you download jQuery UI 1.8.12, have a look around line 281 in `./development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.slider.js`:

```
// workaround for bug #3736 (if both handles of a range are at 0,
// the first is always used as the one with least distance,
// and moving it is obviously prevented by preventing negative ranges)
if( o.range === true && this.values(1) === o.min ) {
   index += 1;
   closestHandle = $( this.handles[index] );
}
```

The bug fix is a good hint where the changes should go, change your condition to the following:

```
if( o.range === true && index == 0 ) {
```

This makes sure if it's a range slider, you always drag the second one, no matter what you do. You can use your code by downloading a custom jQuery UI minified build without the slider component, then include your hacked one manually, or you can hack the minified code.

Look for:

```
if(a.range===true&&this.values(1)===a.min)
```

Change to:

```
if(a.range===true&&g==0)
```

If you don't want to lose the original slider (so you can use it elsewhere on your page), just rename this hacked extension to something else and include it separately.

It would be nice to fix the overlapping bug and to add an option to the slider component to make one of the handles fixed, but I'm afraid that's out of the scope of this answer for now. :)

Comment: The author of this script it using jQuery ui slider v1.7.1 and I did find this: if(e.range==true&&this.values(1)==e.min) and replaced it with the mod you suggested, but it did not make any change?

Comment: That version has been minified differently resulting in different variable names, try changing it to `if(e.range==true&&i==0)`

Comment: That will be man, at least the last time I checked. :) You're welcome. It's just a hack though, not perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Following the example of DarthJDG, I looked at the source code and fixed a bug in another way. As a result, the right slider will have priority when moving to the right and the left slider - to the left.

---

This part of jquery.ui.slider.js

```
        var thisDistance = Math.abs( normValue - self.values(i) );
```

replace to this:

```
        var thisDistance = Math.abs( normValue - (self.values(i) + i) );
```

and delete

```
    if( o.range === true && this.values(1) === o.min ) {
        index += 1;
        closestHandle = $( this.handles[index] );
    }
```

Or in minified version, this part:

```
var l=Math.abs(c-j.values(k));
```

replace to this:

```
var l=Math.abs(c-(j.values(k)+k));
```

and delete this:

```
if(b.range===true&&this.values(1)===b.min){g+=1;e=d(this.handles[g])}
```

Variable names can differ in your version of minified jquery library, but anchor point can be found using this search query in file:

```
.range===true&&this.
```

Hope this helps.